# Doctrine as a verb or adjective

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, etymology

Doctrine should definitely be a verb in the English language, but apparently, it is not. What would then be the word that best suits such a purpose?

Ex: He was *doctrined* to uphold such beliefs.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsingle-word-request%5D+%22indoctrinate%22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for

***[Indoctrinate:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/indoctrinate)***

> to instruct in a doctrine, principle, ideology, etc., especially to imbue with a specific partisan or biased belief or point of view.

(Dictionary.com)

> *He was indoctrinated  to uphold such beliefs*.

[Etymology:](https://www.etymonline.com/word/indoctrinate)

> 1620s, perhaps modeled on French endoctriner or extended from earlier (now obsolete) verb indoctrine, endoctrine, "to instruct" (mid-15c.); see [in-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/in-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_6285) (2) "in" + [doctrine](https://www.etymonline.com/word/doctrine?ref=etymonline_crossreference) + -[ate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/-ate?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_26661) (2)).

(Etymonline)